# Using regex to extract data from structured data

Tags: json, regex, text, structured-data

The problem I'm facing here is that I have a blob of text which contains structured data (in the form of a JSON payload) and I'm interested in extracting the value of one of the keys for a specific JSON instance, picture the structured data inside as the following:

"Item 1": {"key1":"item1_key1_value", "key2":"item1_key2_value", "key3":"item1_key3_value"}, "Item 2": {"key1":"item2_key1_value", "key2":"item2_key2_value", "key3":"item2_key3_value"}

What I would like to use is use regex to grab item1_key2_value for instance. The keys all have the same name but the items are different. So I know which key for which Item I need but am not quite sure of the regex to retrieve that value. I've tried a few approaches to some basic matching but was wondering if any other more experienced regex users could direct me a bit here and explain what I'm doing wrong

1(.*)(?=item1_key2_value.*) will match a chunk of data from here but I'm not sure of the best way to reduce it to the value that I need.

Comment: You should not rely on regex for JSON parsing. Use a JSON parser. It is safer and easier to maintain. What is the programming language you are using for this task?

Comment: I would prefer to do that, but the JSON is contained inside of a large text blob that is not a JSON. I would have to extract that anyway and verify that it's not malformed in order to use a JSON library.

I'm also not using any language in particular, this is on a Google doc fetching things with XPATH, the returned payload is a text blob however that contains JSONs I'm interested in.

Comment: Ok, so you are sure the value you need is a `key2` string value? Have a look at [`"key2":"([^"]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/hN6rN6/1). I am not sure whether you will get the first match only though. Google Docs use JavaScript. Could you show the relevant code you have?

Comment: BTW, if it is Google Docs script, you can add a relevant tag, `google-apps-script`.

Answer (score 0):

The regex syntax for JSON is clearly specified at http://www.json.org.  If you scroll down a little to where it says "A string is a sequence of", you will find the proper string structure.

Assuming the string follows the correct JSON structure, you could use

```
"key2"\s*:\s*"((\\.|[^\\"])*)"
```

where `\s` means whitespace and `*` means 0 or more times.  `\\` means a slosh (backslash) character and can be followed by `.` (any character).  If it does not encounter a slosh, then it instead looks for `[^\\"]`, which means not slosh nor quote.

If you want to be a little more strict to the exact JSON form, you could try

```
"key2"\s*:\s*"((\\["\\/bfnrtu]|[^\\"])*)"
```

which you can see follows the string form on the webpage more closely.